# (Answered) Why is $\frac{1}{x}$ continuous?

Tags: limits, continuity

When x approaches 0 from the left or the right, f(x) heads to positive or negative infinity. So the left and right limits do not equal, and hence the combined limit does not exist. Furthermore, at f(0), the function is not defined.

According to my textbook, the three conditions of continuity are:

1. f(c) is defined
2. limit of f(x) (where x approaches c) exists
3. And f(c) equals the limit

Clearly, 1/x when x = 0 does not meet any of these conditions and thus seems to be discontinuous.

However, 1/x is defined as a continous function. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: $1/x$ is not defined when $x=0$

Comment: If you think of this a s function with domain $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ then it is continuous. You cannot consider it as a  continuous function on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The point is that it *cannot be extended* to a continuous function on the whole $\Bbb R$. Nevertheless, it is continuous in every point of its domain.

Comment: @Berci what is an example of a function that is not continuous on every point of its domain?

Comment: how about $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor $?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Ah, that is true.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have another question. Are the majority of parent functions continuous?